# how to show autocomplete in gwt in tabular format with multiple column?

Tags: java, gwt

Following is my code but it shows only one column in autocomplete but i want shows data in tabular foramte with multiple column[In short i want to show suggestion box in tabular formate]. how i can do that?
Thanks in advance  Please suggest anything..

```
FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
initWidget(panel);
final BulletList list = new BulletList();
list.setStyleName("token-input-list-facebook");
final ListItem item = new ListItem();
item.setStyleName("token-input-input-token-facebook");
final TextBox itemBox = new TextBox();
itemBox.getElement().setAttribute( "style", "outline-color: -moz-use-text-color; outline-style: none; outline-width: medium;");
final SuggestBox box = new SuggestBox(getSuggestions(), itemBox);
box.getElement().setId("suggestion_box");
item.add(box);
list.add(item);
```